# How does the below sed command work?

Tags: unix, sed

Can anyone help me to understand the below sed command?

These are the values I am using:

InsertPoint - 2
TOT - 15
Count- it is the csv file, input to this command.

```
sed -e ''"${InsertPoint}"'s/^[^,]*,//' -e ''"${InsertPoint}"'s/$/, '"${TOT}"'/' ${Count}
```

I need to know, what they are replacing with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two substitution commands here, applied on line 2 of your file. The first one removes first field, the second one adds a field at the end of the line with value `15`.

Basic substitution command with sed have the syntax `s/old text/replacement text/` where `s` can be preceded with a  line number to apply the command to, so:

- `'"${InsertPoint}"'`: at line 2(value of `${InsertPoint}`)
- `s/^[^,]*,//` removes first field by replacing from the start of line(`^`) any number of non comma characters(`[^,]*`) followed by comma(`,`) with nothing(`//`)
- `'"${InsertPoint}"'`: at line 2
- `s/$/, '"${TOT}"'/`: adds a new field by replacing end of line `$` with `15`(value of , `${TOT}`)
- sed command is applied on `${Count}` value file

Comment: Hi SLePort, thanks for the answer.  As per your 2nd point. Suppose I have this line 12,3,4,5,6,78,44 - it will replace 44 with nothing because 44 is followed by comma character of 78 (78,) . Is my understanding is correct? If not please correct me

Comment: Also , please example me the exact use of ^ and * character in the comment

Comment: `^` in `s/^` is to match beginning of the line, it will remove `12,` from your sample input. `*` is for zero or more characters. eg: `,*` zero or more commas, `[^,]*`: zero or more non commas.